AFCI Requirement for basement circuits
I got all the wiring correct on our new basement remodel here in Seattle WA, but the feeder inspection failed with some specifics that I frankly don't understand. The inspector called out the necessity of AFCI protection on the following circuits:

Oven 30A, double
Cooktop 30A, double
Bathroom GFCI 20A
General Outlets 20A
Laundry Outlet 20A

He recommended buying the combo (AFCI and GFCI, dual protection) breakers for my 150A Square D Homeline basement subpanel.
I have pored over the NEC 2023 and found this in 210.12.A:

All 120-volt, single-phase, 15- and 20-ampere branch circuits supplying outlets or devices installed in dwelling unit kitchens, family rooms, dining rooms, living rooms, parlors, libraries, dens, bedrooms, sunrooms, recreation rooms, closets, hallways, laundry areas, or similar rooms or areas shall be protected

My questions:

It's unclear to me why he would call out the cooktop, oven, laundry outlet, general outlets, and GFCI outlets in bathroom, but not the fridge, dishwasher, range hood.

It's also unclear to me why he's suggesting I need AFCI protection on 30a circuits (oven and cooktop, separately). NEC only calls out the need for 15A and 20A circuits. For those I'll use a Homeline 20 Amp Single-Pole Combination Arc Fault Circuit Breaker(HOM120CAFIC) but where is the 30a requirement in NEC and what breaker would I use?



What state are you in?

Is this basement finished living space or left unfinished?

Living space, entirely.

Did you ask him?  If he recommended products he must be at least a little willing to have a conversation.

Remember: the NEC is not a law, it’s just a document. Each locality (usually state level, but sometimes city or county) enacts its own regulations with the force of law. Sometimes they adopt the NEC as-is, but they are always free to amend it. So, read your local code and ask questions of your local inspector.

Remember: the NEC is not a law ... out walks building inspector dressed as Edward Teague... the code is the law.... pulls trigger.


The inspector called out the necessity of AFCI protection on the following circuits:

Oven 30A, double
Cooktop 30A, double


That is false. The hardware doesn't even exist to do that, i.e. 30A AFCI breakers don't exist, least of all 2-pole ones.
So this was a misunderstanding, and you should follow up and determine what was meant to be said for all of those line items.


Bathroom GFCI 20A
General Outlets 20A
Laundry Outlet 20A


One thing that gets people in trouble here is installing a GFCI breaker or a master GFCI receptacle, and using it to protect downline receptacles.  The problem is there's no way for the inspector to know that, they simply see plain receptacles where GFCI protection is required and red-flag it.  That is why there are "GFCI Protected" stickers with GFCIs, and while the literal text of NEC does not say you must use them, NEC 110.3(B) says you must follow instructions and instructions typically 8(C) says you must label.
I say that because perhaps the inspector wasn't saying AFCI but rather GFCI, which would explain each case.
If you think the blue labels are ugly, you may create a different label so long as it is not handwritten. I like Brother and P-touch labelmakers. It also helps to state the location of the reset if it's not the breaker.

Super helpful. Yes, I figured out that 30a breakers like that don't exist real quick. I bought 20a ACFI/GFCI combos for all my 20a circuits. Not cheap but that should satisfy the big man. I'm going to ask in the next inspection if GFCI is required for the 30a circuits. Those damn things are $140 each. Great callout on the labels. I'll get ahead of that! Thanks so much.

@Jeremy FWIW, GFCIs are allowed to be at the first receptacle.
